# Linear transformation intuition

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

While trying out some transformation visualising tools for 2x2 matrices, I observed the the following:

- When the A(1,1) element alone is varied, keeping all other elements fixed (moving the vector where i lands in the transformation, sideways) the eigen vectors rotate together preserving the angle between them.
- When the A(2,1) element is varied, (moving the vector where i lands vertically), the angle between eigen vector was increasing in one direction and decreasing in the other.
- Similarly for the vector where j lands, when it was varied vertically,  the eigen vectors were rotating together and the angles where changing when moved sideways.

So I have a few questions based on this.

- What is the intuition behind this behaviour?
- What is the significance of diagonal elements(which when varied caused the eigen vectors to rotate together) in a linear transformation? (in a visual intuitive sense, like saying determinant is how the unit area get scaled)
- For the transpose of a matrix, the eigen vectors are perpendicular to that of the original matrix. While taking the transpose of a 2x2 matrix, the non diagonal elements are varied by the same amount (the difference between them). The angle between the eigen vectors change by the exact amout that they end up perpendicular. Can the above be used to explain this?

Comment: See the site #3blue1brown-essence of linear algebra#.